# React Keycloak Implementation - Can only be instantiated once

Tags: reactjs, typescript, keycloak

Because it didnt worked in my main application, i created a new raw react project and implemented the simple keycloak login there following the documentation: https://github.com/react-keycloak/react-keycloak/blob/master/packages/web/README.md

Now i get the following Error, that a Keycloak Instance can only be instantiated once.

[Browser-Console Error stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFrVc.png)

App.tsx Code:

```
import './App.css'

import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import keycloak from './keycloak'

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>...</ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

keycloak.ts Code:

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const initOptions = {
    url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/auth',
    realm: 'test',
    clientId: 'test_client'
}

const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions)

export default keycloak
```

I tried different approaches and even asked ChatGPT but nothing helped.
I also read similar questions from stackoverflow but none of the solutions helped.

I tried to do a singleton pattern class for the keycloak instance but this also didnt work.

```
class KeycloakConfiguration {
private static instance: Keycloak.KeycloakInstance | null = null

private constructor() {}

public static getInstance(): Keycloak.KeycloakInstance {
    if (!KeycloakConfiguration.instance) {
        const initOptions = {
            url: 'http://0.0.0.0:8080/auth',
            realm: 'test',
            clientId: 'test_client',
        }

        KeycloakConfiguration.instance = new Keycloak(initOptions)
    }

    return KeycloakConfiguration.instance
}
```

}

Comment: This `const keycloak = new Keycloak(initOptions)` action should be called once, You shouldn't make Keycloack instance more than once.

Comment: It only is called once

Comment: You must provide more context for your current code structure and status to answer the question. One possible issue around this could be that Your component may render multiple times, causing its reinstantiation. You can add a check action within the `keycloack.ts`, which checks for the existing Keycloak instance, and if it was already there, prevent it from creating a new one and return the old one instead.

Comment: @SMAKSS i tried to do it but it also didnt worked

Comment: Can you share what and how did you try it?

Comment: @SMAKSS I added it to the question at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the error was. The Application was wrapped in <React.StrictMode> which caused the application to render twice. After i removed the StrictMode Item, the Error disappeared

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')!).render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
                <App />
            </ReactKeycloakProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </React.StrictMode>
)
```